# /bin/sh: wildcard expansion does not work in script

Tags: shell, wildcards, dash

I am using `dash` as `/bin/sh`. In my script, I have following line:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-????????????/agent.*
```

Which is supposed to match file `/tmp/ssh-abcdefghijkl/agent.1234`. Even when the file exists, the script does not expand the pattern, and the variable instead contains the literal pattern:

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-????????????/agent.*
```

but when I do the same from commandline, it expands the pattern:

```
sh -c 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-????????????/agent.* ; echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK'
/tmp/ssh-abcdefghijkl/agent.1234
```

why does the pattern expansion (wildcard matching) not work in my script ?

Comment: Show the whole script. Or, a complete script that exhibits the problem, and also how you run the script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filename globbing does not happen in assignments like

```bsh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-????????????/agent.*
```

In your code where it *appears* to be working, you get your expected output because you do not quote the expansion of `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.  What your `sh -c` script is doing is assigning the literal string `/tmp/ssh-????????????/agent.*` to `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, and then the shell applies the globbing when you use that variable unquoted with `echo`.

The reason it doesn't behave the same way when you try it on the command line (`echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` prints the literal pattern) could be because you may be using the `zsh` shell (which does these things differently), or you have used `set -f` in the shell to turn off filename globbing, or there are simply no matching pathnames.

If you want to do something like what you are proposing, then use

```bsh
set -- /tmp/ssh-????????????/agent.*
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$1
```

This first sets the positional parameters to all pathnames that match the given pattern (in lexical order).  It then assigns the *first* of these pathnames to the variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

If no pathnames match the pattern, the pattern will be left unexpanded and later assigned to the variable as it is.

In the `bash` shell, you could use a named array in place of the positional parameters:

```bsh
names=( /tmp/ssh-????????????/agent.* )
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${names[0]}
```

Comment: Bearing in mind that in sh or bash, if the glob doesn't match any file, the pattern is left unexpanded (in bash, the `failglob` or `nullglob` options can be used to avoid that. See also the `N` glob qualifier in `zsh` or the `~(N)` glob operator in ksh93).

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:dash], so why ignore that and address `bash` and `zsh` instead?

Comment: @TobySpeight The user is using `dash` in a script, yes. It is unclear what the interactive shell is that they are testing things in (their middle code section).  My mentioning of `bash` at the very end is just an added extra.